# Error of deadlock while piping in gnuplot

Tags: python, pipe, system, stdin, popen

Trying to make a test experiment of realtime plotting via pipes.

```
gp = os.popen("gnuplot -persist", 'w')

data = [(x,x*x) for x in range(10)]
        print data
        print >> gp, "set grid"
        print >> gp, "show grid"

data = []
os.remove('data.txt')
f = open('data.txt', 'a')
f.write("0.000000 0.000000\n")
f.write("1.000000 1.000000\n")
f.close()
print >> gp, "plot 'data.txt' volatile with lines"
gp.flush()
#time.sleep(2)
for x in range(2,10):
    f = open('data.txt', 'a')
    f.write("%f %f\n"%(x,x*x))
    f.close()
        gp.flush()
        #time.sleep(1) # deadlock here
        gp.flush()
```

This works untill I uncomment time.sleep(1) in cycle. Have added gp.flush() between all the sleeps but no result. How can  I handle popens with sleep?

Comment: Why do you want to sleep?

Comment: For comportable viewing.

Comment: (1) use `subprocess` module that provides more control (2) `gp.flush()` is useless here unless you write to the pipe (you don't in the loop) (3) are you sure that appending data to a file works with gnuplot? (4) are you sure there is no better way to pass "real-time" data to gnuplot other than appending to a file?

Comment: "This works untill I uncomment time.sleep(1) in cycle"...about better way I answered another question here - no answers. Subprocess gives the same result.